# Using $watch in directive

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, watch

I have a directive in my CoffeeScript Angular project in which I want to observe/watch an array of contacts. I'm using the `controllerAs` syntax. As I've read about `$watch`, I thought I'll give it a try. Here is some example code:

```
app.directive 'labelSelect', [
  "Label"
  "Contact"
  "$scope"
  (Label, Contact, $scope) ->

  restrict: 'E'
  templateUrl: '/assets/templates/label-select.html'
  controllerAs: 'ls'

  controller: ->

    $scope.$watchCollection "this.contacts", (value) ->
      @somefunciton()

    @somefunction = ->
      console.log 'observer fired'
```

]

When I load the site, I get the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- labelSelectDirective
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is this the correct way to use the `$watch` functionality when using the `controller as` syntax? Thanks!

**Update:**
The solution was to only not inject `$scope` but to use it as a parameter here:

```
controller: ($scope) ->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove $scope from directive injection.

Add as parameter in controller function.

Comment: At first I misunderstood what you meant by `controller function`. Thanks a lot!